# Why does forEach work with e.target.children but not getElementById children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have an SVG/button that contains several color elements. The idea is to have the elements slide in, one-by-one on mouseEnter, and leave through the opposite side on mouseLeave, then reset so it can be performed again.

When using [...e.target.children] to create an array, the subsequent forEach function works correctly. When using getElementById and converting to array, I am getting the error "is not a function.

The former returns a list of actual elements while the latter returns just a list. How can I correctly convert the array so the forEach function works?

```
<svg id="HeroButton" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 270 48">
  <title>HeroButton</title>
  <polygon className="pink" points="29 23 52 0 15 0 0 0 0 48 15 48 54 48 29 23" fill="#ed3e88"/>
  <polygon className="yellow" points="97.5 40.5 114 24 96 24 96 0 52 0 29 23 54 48 82 48 82 40.5 97.5 40.5" fill="#fded52"/>
  <polygon className="turq" points="155.5 19.5 175 0 116 0 96 0 96 24 114 24 97.5 40.5 82 40.5 82 48 116 48 156.5 48 185 19.5 155.5 19.5" fill="#17adcb"/>
  <polygon className="beige" points="224.5 33 224.5 13.5 238 0 189 0 175 0 155.5 19.5 185 19.5 156.5 48 189 48 239.5 48 224.5 33" fill="#ffffc7"/>
  <polygon className="turq2" points="243 0 238 0 224.5 13.5 224.5 33 239.5 48 243 48 270 48 270 0 243 0" fill="#17adcb"/>
</svg>
```

```
export default class HeroButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      translate: "translateX(100%)",
      opacity: 1
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    // const polygons = [...document.getElementById('HeroButton').children;
    const polygons = Array.from(document.getElementById('HeroButton').children);
    console.log({polygons})
    this.updatePolygons(polygons);
    this.setState({
      translate: "translateX(-100%)",
      opacity: 0
    });
  };
  handleMouseEnter = (polygons) => {
    this.updatePolygons(polygons)
  };
  handleMouseLeave = (polygons) => {
    this.setState({
      translate: "translateX(100%)",
      opacity: 1
    });
  };
  updatePolygons = (polygons) => {
    // const polygons = [...e.target.children];
    polygons.forEach(child => {
      child.style.transform = this.state.translate;
      child.style.opacity = this.state.opacity;
    });
  };
  render() {
    return(
      <button>
        <HeroButtonSVG
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        />
        <span>Check out my work<i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </button>
    );
  };
};
```

```
.Hero button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.Hero button svg {
  display: flex;
  width: 275px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.Hero button svg polygon {
  /* transform: translateX(100%); */
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.Hero button svg polygon.yellow {
  transition-delay: .1s;
}

.Hero button svg polygon.turq {
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.Hero button svg polygon.beige {
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

.Hero button svg polygon.turq2 {
  transition-delay: .4s;
}

.Hero button span {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: var(--medium);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Hero button span i {
  margin-left: var(--small);
}
```

Comment: What makes you say it doesn't? and what is `"` in `error "is not a function` - Also, what makes you think `handleMouseEnter` is going to be called with an array?

Comment: "polygons.forEach is not a function". I just know that one way gives me an error and the other does not. Perhaps there is something else wrong with my code?

Comment: perhaps on initial render, `polygon` is null.

Comment: that's the mouseenter problem ... because the argument is not an array

Comment: Yea actually polygons starts as an array but is returning a class object inside the updatePolygons function so its not iterable but idk why its being changed. Any ideas about that? Regarding the props part, that is still a little confusing to me so I will go back into the react tools and see if I can update that. Could you provide an example maybe?

Comment: @gumball do you still need any help integrating this? In my last message I provided a sandbox for you which I think has the solution you're looking for.

Comment: @Christopher Ngo I think my issue shifted and I may end up in another post. I will tag you in it if I do. Thanks!

Comment: @gumball cool! I'd be happy to help out, I'm really interested in this animation you're trying to make. When you have a chance, please consider marking my solution as the answer if you feel that it contributed to solving this part of your feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the two pieces of code you have here:

### Event Handler

```
  updatePolygons = (polygons) => {
    // const polygons = [...e.target.children];
    polygons.forEach(child => {
      child.style.transform = this.state.translate;
      child.style.opacity = this.state.opacity;
    });
  };
```

### Event Listener

```
    <HeroButtonSVG
      onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
    />
```

The value that gets passed into `updatedPolygons()` is not an array. Therefore it does not have a method called `forEach()`. Which is why you get the error "polygons.forEach() is not a function" when you run this code.

However, the actual value that gets passed is the `event`, an object `{}`. When you go deeper into the properties, you can access the children array like `event.target.children`, which is an array you can iterate over. So `.forEach()` is legal. Hence `[...event.target.children]`

It looks like you're trying to use the `polygons` variable you defined inside `componentDidMount()`. However, that `polygons` is not available outside `componentDidMount()`. You can explicitly create a polygons property and access/mutate it from anywhere in your component.

Additionally, I've created some extra logic to help you create the animation you want. See working code and sandbox below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import HeroButtonSVG from "./HeroButtonSVG";

import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      translate: "translateX(100%)",
      opacity: 1
    };
  }

  polygons = [];

  componentDidMount() {
    // const polygons = [...document.getElementById('HeroButton').children;
    this.polygons = Array.from(document.getElementById("HeroButton").children);
    this.setState(
      {
        translate: "translateX(100%)",
        opacity: 0
      },
      () => this.updatePolygons()
    );
  }
  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        translate: "translateX(0%)",
        opacity: 1
      },
      () => this.updatePolygons()
    );
  };
  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        translate: "translateX(100%)",
        opacity: 0
      },
      () => this.updatePolygons()
    );
  };
  updatePolygons = () => {
    // const polygons = [...e.target.children];
    this.polygons.forEach(child => {
      child.style.transform = this.state.translate;
      child.style.opacity = this.state.opacity;
    });

    console.log(this.polygons);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Hero">
        <button>
          <HeroButtonSVG
            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
          />
          <span>
            Check out my work
            <i className="fas fa-chevron-right" />
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

So with the polygons property defined, you can access it from anywhere in your component. Additionally, you do not need to explicitly pass it to your event-handlers. Simply use `this.polygons` anytime you want to use it.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-surf-v87m7

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In componentDidMount, I am showing that "polygons" is an array. I think I am passing the polygons array incorrectly to updatePolyguns but I do not know why. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: The polygons variable you defined in componentDidMount() is only available inside that execution scope (ie, polygons is not defined outside of that function). If you want, you can can define a property called  `this.polygons` instead and access it across your component. I can show you.

Comment: I would be grateful if you did!

Comment: @gumball try solution above, let me know if that works.

Comment: I def understand your approach but I am getting an error on line 19 "cannot read property 'children' of null."

Comment: @gumball seems to be something wrong with `document.getElementById('HeroButton')` do we know if element with this id is mounted?

Comment: I am not 100%. I moved the id to the render object below -> <HeroButton id="HeroButton" /> if that helps.

Comment: @gumball doesn't seem to be an issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-curie-x84ni  Although to be honest, I'm not sure wht you expect the visual change to be.

Comment: I have a working version. I will add the css to the above code so you can see the visual effect. The polygons come in from the right leave through the left. The problem I am really trying to solve is to move the polygons back to the right without being seen so the hover effect can happen again.I added the css so maybe that can give you a better picture. I appreciate you trying to work through this with me lol

Comment: I see, that might be a different problem altogether. Regarding your current question, this seems to do the trick :) https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-curie-x84ni

Comment: It is a different problem. I think I found the correct solution and I may try to integrate yours as well. Thanks you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196954/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-gumball).

Answer (score -1):

gumball,
you can take the children in a different array and then can use the forEach on that array.

```
const el = document.getElementsByClassName('js-favorite-btn s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer py8')
```

when using el[0].children.forEach gives me error

```
el[0].children.forEach is not a function
```

But when using

```
const arr = [el[0].children]
```

and then running a forEach works.
I hope this works with you.